# I want to read a log file in flume which is on the different server

Tags: hadoop, flume

I want to read a log file from different server in flume which is up and running on some different server.......so for doing so how can I achive this by changing my **flume-conf.properties** file.......what should i write in the configuration file of flume to achieve this...

```
a1.sources = AspectJ
a1.channels = memoryChannel
a1.sinks = kafkaSink
a1.sources.AspectJ.type = com.flume.MySource
a1.sources.AspectJ.command = tail -F /tmp/data/Log.txt
```

for achiving this what should I write in place of 
**a1.sources.AspectJ.command = tail -F /tmp/data/Log.txt**

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs a little more as your current example is a long way from what you need. You need to set the type of the channel and the sink as well as setting the channel for the source and the sink. The type of the sources is also not an actual Flume source so you'll need to fix that.

Comment: yes I will set the type of my channel for the sink as well as for the source but i want to know what should i write in the a1.sources.AspectJ.command= ????   .......should I specify the server name here???

Comment: No the command is as you've set it - if you use the Exec source.

Comment: If you just want to copy a file then use the Spool source

Comment: The question should be improved by specifying were the data is intended to be store in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want to ask is that, if Flume is setup on host 'F' and your log files exists on host 'L', how will you configure flume to read log files from host 'L', correct ?

If so, then you need to setup Flume on host 'L' and not on 'F'. Setup flume on the same host where the log files are and setup the Sink to point to Kafka topic.

Comment: Alternatively, you can configure an **Appender** in the log generating application that will say produce logs in SYSLOG format and **send** it to your Flume instance running on host 'F'. In this case your Flume configuration needs to configure a SYSLOG source only.